# Disable Picture in Picture for iPad Air in appcelerator

Tags: html, ios, appcelerator

How to disable or hide picture in picture icon in video player which using HTML video tag in iPad Air device. Picture in Picture / Multitasking functionality added in iOS 9 provide for limited device edition. Eg: iPad Air. User Play around the iPad while video playing in multitasking mode.

Actual Result: When user trying to maximize it, video is closed.
Expected Result: It should maximize and navigate to respective application. Else we need option to disable the icon in HTML video tag.

Do we have any control on Appcelerator to hide or disable the icon (Refer below Screenshot)?

Do we have any CSS3 properties to disable via video tag style?

Added video tag in HTML and referred local video path to play via webview (HTML content loaded). Struct with this issue past two weeks.

[Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RxYiw.png)

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: so... why do you use HTML with Appcelerator?

Comment: Due some functionality requirement we decided to use HTML video tag.....

Comment: try http://docs.appcelerator.com/platform/latest/#!/api/Titanium.Media.VideoPlayer

Comment: We have to show sub-titles for the video, that is not supported in the appcelerator API.